# How to convert the date format

Tags: java, date

I have a date format as "Nov 10,1980" in a string format(String str="Nov 10, 1980"), and i want to convert it to 1980-11-10. can any one tell me how to do that using java.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first parse it from the original text format, then format the result using the format you want it to end up as. You can use [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) for this, or [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net) (which is generally a much better date/time API).

Sample code using `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {        
        String inputText = "Nov 10,1980";

        TimeZone utc = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC");

        // Or dd instead of d - it depends whether you'd use "Nov 08,1980"
        // or "Nov 8,1980" etc.
        SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d,yyyy",
                                                            Locale.US);
        inputFormat.setTimeZone(utc);

        SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd",
                                                             Locale.US);
        outputFormat.setTimeZone(utc);

        Date parsed = inputFormat.parse(inputText);
        String outputText = outputFormat.format(parsed);

        System.out.println(outputText); // 1980-11-10
    }
}
```

Note that:

- I've explicitly specified the locale to use; otherwise if you try to parse the text on a system with (say) a French default locale, it will try to parse it using French month names.
- I've explicitly set the time zone as UTC to avoid any daylight saving time issues (where a particular value could be ambiguous or even non-existent in the default time zone)

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
            Date date = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf;
    sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-DD");
    System.out.println(sdf.format(date));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
try {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy");
    Date strDt = sdf1.parse("Nov 10, 1980");
    SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    System.out.println(sdf2.format(strDt));
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

Also, quoted below is a notice from the [home page of **Joda-Time**](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

> Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtfInput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM d,u", Locale.ENGLISH);
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("Nov 10,1980", dtfInput);
        System.out.println(date);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
1980-11-10
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/VY7l4U)

Notice that I have not used a `DateTimeFormatter` to format the `LocalDate` because your desired format is the same as the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format which is also the standard used for `java.time` API. Check the [`LocalDate#toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#toString--) documentation for more details.

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String req_date = dateFormat.format(DATE)
System.out.println(req_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use two [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)s. One to parse, one to format. For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    DateFormat parseFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd,yyyy");
    DateFormat displayFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

    Date date = parseFormat.parse("Nov 10,1980");
    String s = displayFormat.format(date);
    System.err.println(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the SimpleDateFormat to get the result you want